# Android: FusedLocationProviderClient doesn't call onLocationResult() when device location is already enabled

Tags: android, google-maps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have recently stared to get issues as my `FusedLocationProviderClient` doesn't call the `onLocationResult()` method of `LocationCallback` when the device location is already enabled but has no problems to do so when I ask user to enable the location himself first (disabled at first). Below I am posting my code (I do not show how I obtain location permission beforehand) called from `onCreate()`:

```
public void onReady() {

    LocationRequest locReq = LocationRequest.create();

    LocationSettingsRequest request = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locReq)
            .build();
    LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
            .checkLocationSettings(request)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this::handleSettingsResponse);
}

private void handleSettingsResponse(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
        try {
            LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            if (response != null) {
                LocationSettingsStates states = response.getLocationSettingsStates();
                if (states.isLocationPresent() && states.isLocationUsable()) {
                    findLocation();
                } else {
                    failure()
                }
            }
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            copeWithFailure(e);
        }
    }

 private void copeWithFailure(Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            try {
                ((ResolvableApiException) e).startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLUTION);//I call findLocation() if successful
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                failure()
            }
        }
    }

private void findLocation() {
        FusedLocationProviderClient client =
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    startingLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                    startingLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                }}

        LocationRequest locaReq = LocationRequest()
            .setNumUpdates(1)
            .setExpirationDuration(5500)
            .setInterval(5000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        client.requestLocationUpdates(locaReq,
                mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                });
 }
```

This worked without problems before with pre-enabled location.